# How to Upload and Display File Using Play Framework and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, playframework

I have one scenario: I am uploading one file at some server location using: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaFileUpload ,

//Uploading file:

```
<input type="file" name="fileUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
```

And from the below code, I am uploading the above uploaded file and getting/displaying it on my view page like(After clicking the Submit button):

```
<input type="file" id="inputfile">
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submitfile">
```

jQuery:

```
$("#submitfile").click(function(){
    var path1 =$('input[type=file]').val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');//uploaded file names 
    //adding the Play framework server path for Application to get the image(s) file(s) path
    var filespath = '/files/images/'+path1;//giving my uploaded files path here

    });
```

But my requirement is that: I need only one  type which does both: accepts/uploads the file at server location and returns/displays the same file path from server location on my view page ? I am struggling for it. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a similar issue to [33163555](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33163555/how-to-upload-file-using-jquery-ajax-in-play-framework-server-on-button-click). That question has the following example:

**Edit:** Reference [2320069](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload) for support on ajax file uploads & alternatives:

> FormData support starts from following desktop browsers versions. IE
>   10+, Firefox 4.0+, Chrome 7+, Safari 5+, Opera 12+

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="" value="Upload" />
</form>

<script>
$('#submit').click(function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var file = $('#file').get(0).files[0];
   var formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('file', file);
   $.ajax({
       url: 'upload',
       data: formData,
       type: 'POST',
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       beforeSend: function (data) {
         alert('Are you sure you want to upload document?');
       },
       success: function (data) {
         //call your jQuery action here
         alert('Upload completed: ' + data);
       },
       error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
       }
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

In your routes you have:

```
POST /upload controllers.Application.upload()
```

Where your controller method returns the filepath:

```
public static Result upload() {
  MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
  FilePart fileP = body.getFile("file");
  if (fileP != null) {
    File file = fileP.getFile();
    //If we want to move from temp
    //FileUtils.moveFile(file.getCanonicalPath(), "FileB"); 
    return ok(file.getCanonicalPath());
  } else {
    return badRequest("Upload Error");    
  }
}
```

And you can perform your custom jQuery action in the ajax success callback

Comment: I am getting Internal Server Error

Comment: Can we implement it above like : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209460/how-to-redirect-to-same-overlay-on-return-statement-in-play-framework

Comment: Oh sorry haha. I didn't realize you posted my referenced question. Editing my answer based on [2320069](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload) , [20452853](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20452853/uploading-files-via-jquery-object-formdata-is-provided-and-no-file-name-get-re), [6974684](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery) which say that you need to store your file into an ajax formData object before sending, or take another approach

Comment: Excellent, It's working great !! Hat's off !! You saved me !!

Comment: I am getting internal server error for above ajax call